# How to create a list of tuples using a for loop

Tags: python

I've populated `results` with `test_score`, but how can I add `train_score` to `results` so that it's a list of 10 tuples like: (`train_score`, `test_score`)?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

results = []

for i in list(range(1, 11)):
    
    clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = i, random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    test_score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
    train_score = clf.score(X_train, y_train)
    
    results.append(test_score)
    
results
```

Comment: I think list(range()) is not necessary, range() will work fine.

Comment: It's right there in your question: you write `(train_score, test_score)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the tuple to your list :
 `results.append((train_score,test_score))`

Also, note than `for i in list(range(1, 11))` is unnecessary in a for loop. 
`for i in range(1, 11)` is sufficient since it returns a range object which is iterable.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
...
results.append((train_score, test_score))
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a tuple instance before

```
t = (test_score, train_score)
results.append(t)
```